# Need explanations about this Typescript code snippet?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The `type` in the constructor has two default values `active` or `finished`. But I think there should be a parameter type such as `number` or `string`.

Any explanation about this?

```
class ProjectList{
    templateElement: HTMLTemplateElement;

    constructor(private type: 'active' | 'finished'){
    
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter type *is* `'active' | 'finished'`. It's not a default value - it's that those are the only two possible arguments the function can be provided with. `number` or `string` would both be outside the permitted values.

Comment: See [Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and scroll down to _"literal unions"_

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring that `type` is a `string` restricted to only possible 2 values.  A default can also be declared, like this:

```js
class ProjectList{
    templateElement: HTMLTemplateElement;

    constructor(private type: 'active' | 'finished' = 'active'){
    
    }
}
```